# REACT:state of form elements are getting set to default on clicking to a button,page is re-rendering after interaction and clicking on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

the issue is that whenever i click on Click me button it should display the corresponding error message on ui but instead when i click on the button the page gets re rendered. I am performing tasks based on the current state,as states are getting set to default on render, i am not able to do so. and after the 1st or 2nd submit the error message persists but when i enter some value in the textbox and then again submit,the entered values are lost and a fresh clean form is displayed.
the same is happening for all my form fields.

Comment: Assuming this `Button` component ends up rendering a normal `button` tag, the default action of a button from within a `form` is to submit. This will **reload** the page not re-render, and a reload will reset your state (since it will have been unmounted and remounted). I don't see `this.myMethod` defined, but within that function you just need to add `.preventDefault()` on the event object.

Comment: Not having the implementation of `Button` makes this guesswork, but once again, assuming it behaves like I'd expect, you'd just need to change your function to this: `onProceedToPayClicked = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); ..rest of your code`. If that does not work, please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).